# Generación de oraciones aleatorias

Tags: c, punteros, array

Mi pregunta ahora es, ¿Cómo puedo convertir el primer caracter de cada una de las cadenas de caracteres del primer arreglo de punteros, 'article', a mayúscula?, para que, al momento de mostrar las oraciones generadas aleatoriamente, se empiece con una letra mayúscula.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Function prototypes. */
void generateSentences(const char *article_gen[], const char *noun_gen[], const char *verb_gen[], const char *preposition_gen[]);


int main()
{
    const char *article[5] = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};
    const char *noun[5] = {"boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car"};
    const char *verb[5] = {"drove", "jumped", "ran", "waled", "skipped"};
    const char *preposition[5] = {"to", "from", "over", "under", "on"}; 

    srand(time(0));

    generateSentences(article,noun,verb,preposition);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void generateSentences(const char *article_gen[], const char *noun_gen[], const char *verb_gen[], const char *preposition_gen[])
{
    int cant;
    int sub_article1;
    int sub_article2;
    int sub_noun1;
    int sub_noun2;
    int sub_verb;
    int sub_preposition;

    for(cant = 1; cant <= 20; cant++)
    {
        sub_article1 = rand()%5;
        sub_article2 = rand()%5;
        sub_noun1 = rand()%5;
        sub_noun2 = rand()%5;
        sub_verb = rand()%5;
        sub_preposition = rand()%5;

        printf("\n%s %s %s %s %s %s.\n", article_gen[sub_article1], noun_gen[sub_noun1], verb_gen[sub_verb], preposition_gen[sub_preposition], article_gen[sub_article2], noun_gen[sub_noun2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: A mí tu código me genera 20.

Comment: Cierto, hubo un error de sintaxis que no corregí ... Ya corre perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta alternativa

```
void generateSentences(const char *article_gen[], const char *noun_gen[], const char *verb_gen[], const char *preposition_gen[])
{
    int cant;
    int sub_article1;
    int sub_article2;
    int sub_noun1;
    int sub_noun2;
    int sub_verb;
    int sub_preposition;
    char currentArticle[255];

    for(cant = 1; cant <= 20; cant++)
    {
        sub_article1 = rand()%5;
        sub_article2 = rand()%5;
        sub_noun1 = rand()%5;
        sub_noun2 = rand()%5;
        sub_verb = rand()%5;
        sub_preposition = rand()%5;

        //copio el contenido a una variable temporal
        strcpy(currentArticle,article_gen[sub_article1]);
        //de minisculas a mayusculas
        currentArticle[0]-=' ';

        printf("\n%s %s %s %s %s %s.\n", currentArticle, noun_gen[sub_noun1], verb_gen[sub_verb], preposition_gen[sub_preposition], article_gen[sub_article2], noun_gen[sub_noun2]);
    }
}
```

Me creo una variable llamada currentArticle a la cual le voy a copiar el articulo que se iterando en ese momento y lo voy a modificar para pasar su primer letra de minuscula a mayuscula restando 32 en decimal o su equivalente que es un espacio en blanco.

Otra forma es usar la funcion toUpper http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @JesúsFragoso, si esta pregunta solución tu problema, por favor, [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).